# Unable to install wine

Tags: software-installation, wine

whenever i want to install wine it five me error even some other software too give me error i try to install it from terminal

my command was this = sudo apt-get install wine

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by he
```

when i try to install it from software center. it give me following error.

```
This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
```

in detailt

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package
```

im so frustrated because of this. i really want to un install. i try to search the same problem but no solution worked for me can anyone help me please.

Comment: can you run "sudo apt-get install -f" and put the output in you're post.

Comment: sudo apt-get install -f also giving me the same error @neil

Comment: what same error is it giving you copy it here.

Comment: give the output of "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

Comment: this is output for the intall -f command 

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a this command didnt give me any output

Comment: What is the out put of this command. sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

Answer (score 1):

Nothing Seems to be wrong with your package system

you may need to download and install new updates open up a terminal and type in

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

now try to install wine1.6 open up a terminal and type in

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

if that still dose not work open up `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` with a text editer.

```
sudo nano /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
```

Locate any "broken" packages and remove them with `sudo apt-get remove <package>` if you have trouble locating the broken packages in the apt.log copy its text and add it to you're post by editing it.

Ok you have broken packages remove them by typing in this command.

```
sudo apt-get remove aptitude:i386 brasero wine
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

then install wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Comment: Log time: 2015-10-24 09:10:23.034442
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 3
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 3
Investigating (0) aptitude [ i386 ] < 0.6.6-1ubuntu1 -> 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 > ( admin )
Broken aptitude:i386 Depends on libapt-pkg4.12 [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.5 > ( admin ) (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6)
  Considering libapt-pkg4.12:i386 0 as a solution to aptitude:i386 1
  Removing aptitude:i386 rather than change libapt-pkg4.12:i386
Done
MarkUpgrade() called on a non-upgrable pkg: 'brasero'
ERROR:root:Upgrading 'brasero' failed
Log time: 2015-10-24 09

Comment: edited my post.

Comment: same error again .

Comment: Log time: 2015-10-24 09:10:23.034442
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 3
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 3
Investigating (0) aptitude [ i386 ] < 0.6.6-1ubuntu1 -> 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 > ( admin )
Broken aptitude:i386 Depends on libapt-pkg4.12 [ i386 ] < none -> 1.0.1ubuntu2.5 > ( admin ) (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6)
  Considering libapt-pkg4.12:i386 0 as a solution to aptitude:i386 1
  Removing aptitude:i386 rather than change libapt-pkg4.12:i386
Done
MarkUpgrade() called on a non-upgrable pkg: 'brasero'
ERROR:root:Upgrading 'brasero' failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open the terminal and try the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a       
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

then Go to ubuntu software center ==> Edit ==> Software Sources ==> Download From ==> Select main server

uninstall wine :

```
sudo apt-get remove wine
rm -rf ~/.wine
```

After that restart your computer go to software center and type wine and install it
[image]

Comment: this error again bro .. mybe i need to uninstall ubuntu fed up now

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

unity-control-center: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:4.0-0ubuntu11.1 is to be installed
                      Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
wine1.6: Depends: wine1.6-amd64 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is a virtual package